# Retrieve column names from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to retrieve the column headers for html  headers from a MySQL query. The structure of my application is such that the column headers aren't static (sometimes there are 4, sometimes 7, etc.) For some unbearable reason I can't find a simple way to get the column names from any given query.

My end goal is to output an html table from the query.

Comment: your code and table structure ?

Comment: You need `SHOW COLUMNS FROM myTable`

Comment: @SuperNoob You realize the answer you marked as correct was written today and is a duplicate of my answer, right?  As in, he actually copied and pasted my answer.  Check out the mistake I made where I added the code comment saying both foreach statements were column names instead of the lower being the column value...

Comment: I don't know why people marked this question as duplicate, since it ask a different thing =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you get the query as an associative array, you can do something like this:

```
$query = "Select [stuff]";
$results = mysql_query($query);
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    if ($i < 1) {
        foreach($row as $key => $val) {
            echo $key;//column name
        }
    }

    //Do other stuff
    $i++;
}
```

And yes, I know they should be doing mysqli_..., but this is my example using old mysql_...

**Edit**

To expand on this:

```
$query = "Select [stuff]";
$results = mysql_query($query);
$i = 0;

echo "<table>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    if ($i < 1) {
        foreach($row as $key => $val) {
            echo "<td>".$key."</td>";//column name
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        echo "<td>".$val."</td>";//column name
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    //Do other stuff
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: THIS is the correct answer. In it's original form.  I had similarly programmed my code, but I was using mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: @SuperNoob Thanks, imagine my surprise when I seen that Rizwan had straight copied my answer.  :/  Literally.  I appreciate the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function [mysql_list_fields](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php)  for getting column names.

Answer (score 0):

Code below gets data from sql. Including header column

```
// Data, depends on your sql statement
$sql_dt = array(); // make sure it is array

foreach( $sql_dt as $key => $val ) {    
$data[] = <<< EOH
  <tr>
    <th>$val['column_name']</th> <tr/>
    <th>$val['column_age']</th>
  <tr/>
EOH;
}

$table_dt = implode( $data );
echo <<< EOT
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th> <tr/>
    <th>Age</th>
  <tr/>
  {$table_dt}
<table/>
EOT;
```